# Convert JSON to GeoJSON frontend

Tags: json, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I have json from an open data API that I need to convert into geojson so that it can be displayed as layer on my Mapbox map. I am using Mapbox GL JS library: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/. Here's the link to the open data json api: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/64uk-42ks.json.

I can successfully fetch the json api and print it to console, but now I need to convert it to a geojson. I know that I can do this entirely frontend because it is open data.

Here's my code:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/niki12step/ck8q9fgpx00d91ipipual7mrl', // replace this with your style URL
  center: [-73.961581,40.683868],
  zoom: 9.5
})

var pluto_url = 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/64uk-42ks.json'

getData();

async function getData () {
   await fetch(pluto_url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
}
```

Comment: That's a good statement of what you're trying to achieve. Where are you stuck?

Comment: have really no clue on how to proceed from fetching the json to converting it geojson. I can't find anything else on stack overflow to guide me towards that.

Comment: A good place to start is looking at the GeoJSON specification (https://github.com/stevage/geojson-spec), looking at the JSON you have, then seeing how you can convert one into the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A GeoJSON file typically looks like this:

```
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
   {
     "type": "Feature",
     "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates": [75, 25]
     },
     "properties": {
        "name": "earth"
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

"features" is the list of all your features. Each feature is a object with the keys "type", "geometry" and "properties" and eventually "id".

That means you have to loop through all data points in your JSON file and convert it to this format. This could look like this:

```
const pluto_url = 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/64uk-42ks.json';
getData();

async function getData () {
   let mygeojson = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": []}
   await fetch(pluto_url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    for(let point of data){
      let coordinate = [parseFloat(point.longitude), parseFloat(point.latitude)];
      let properties = point;
      delete properties.longitude;
      delete properties.latitude;          
      let feature = {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": coordinate}, "properties": properties}
      mygeojson.features.push(feature);
    }
  });
  console.log(mygeojson);
}
```

I assumed that you only have Point geometries. I used `parsedFloat()` because coordinates are stored as String in your file but the GeoJSON format required float values. With `delete properties.longitude` and `delete properties.latitude` I achieve that the coordinates are not needlessly part of the properties field.

Comment: this definitely worked because when I console.log the output is a FeatureCollection object. However, when I try to assign a new variable to the geojson that was created so that it can be added as a layer on the map, the error message I get is "Input data is not a valid geojson object". I need to figure out how to make the geojson object into a new variable now.

Comment: You may get this error if you use the variable directly after the function call without waiting till the function has resolved. Keep in mind that it is an asynchronous function.

Comment: Yes. I figured it out. I called the variable before the function and fixed it.